# Filter multiple categories Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

How can I filter multiple words in a column? (for example, I want to filter the words `golf` and `ski` to show up in my filter)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may use an additional column to filter categories in place. Here's the formula to check if any text matches  "golf" or "ski" :

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2,"ski|golf")
```

It will give `True` if cell A2 contains any word "golf" or "ski". If you want to check more then two words, the easy way is to write them into a separate list, say K1:K3:

```
golf
ski
badminton
```

and then use this formula `join("|", K1:K3)` will give text "golf|sky|badminton", so final check formula is:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2, join("|", K1:K3))
```

where K1:K3 is list with desired text to match.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your 3 unique sport values to 3 additional columns:
**Ski Badminton Golf**

where you could filter any sport with values:
**true/false** select

Cell formula for the additional columns:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND(E$3,$B4)),TRUE(),FALSE())
```

my example
[image: additional hidden columns]

**UPD:**

#### Second solution -

Additional one column with unique left-column value and filter by search

I've publish my google sheet for details [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TqvvzqvEnAUBoycC90OaAirXksS7sAWjO2U3tevjwFs/edit?pref=2&pli=1#gid=2026369377)

[image: inline filter]

Comment: But i have over 12 sports and another 15 different stuff to add to the category part. They should all be in the same column because they are a column. And the sports as well.

Comment: So either hidden additional column groups or transpon to additional table

https://pp.vk.me/c631427/v631427840/2d574/tmtZKJW_dn0.jpg

Comment: I've found another way. And I think this is the smallest workaround. (upd)